# Ionic 3 : npm install admob-free UNMEET PEER DEPENDENCIES

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, admob, ionic3, npm-install

Ionic 3 : npm install admob-free UNMEET PEER DEPENDENCIES.
I cannot import the AdmobFree Library to the Ionic 3 project. It show error when i do npm install.

When I type :

```
npm install --save @ionic-native/admob-free
```

it show :

```
+-- @ionic-native/admob-free@4.5.2
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @ionic-native/core@4.4.0

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN @ionic-native/admob@3.14.0 requires a peer of @ionic-native/core@^3.6.0 but none was installed.
```

for more detal, this is my package.json :

```
{
  "name": "AcehTourismMap",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.3",
    "@ionic-native/admob": "^3.14.0",
    "@ionic-native/admob-free": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/launch-navigator": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^4.4.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "cordova-admob-sdk": "^0.13.1",
    "cordova-android": "~7.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-actionsheet": "^2.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-admob-free": "^0.13.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.4",
    "cordova-plugin-dialogs": "^2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.1.16",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.1",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.1",
    "cordova-promise-polyfill": "0.0.2",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator": "^4.1.3",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.6",
    "typescript": "2.4.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator": {},
      "cordova-plugin-admob-free": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

How to fix this? The plugin/library not downloaded, and I cannot import the AdmobFree library

```
import { AdMobFree } from '@ionic-native/admob-free';
```

Thank you for the answer, I really appreciate, thank you......

Comment: can you include your package.json? which version of `@ionic-native/core` is installed?

Comment: I check on package.json. I use : "@ionic-native/core": "4.4.0"

Comment: can you add the package.json to question? thats odd.

Comment: i already add the package.json

Comment: maybe `"@ionic-native/admob": "^3.14.0",` needs to be updated